# How to get the accessToken from Facebook SDK

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm using the latest Facebook's SDK, and I need to get the token to send to a server. Following the Facebook's documentation the way to get the token is FBSession *session and to get the accessToken property from the session like this `session.accessToken`but xCode keeps telling me this is deprecated.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just found the answer. I will leave it here so it helps someone else!

```
[session accessTokenData].accessToken
```